# Integer solutions to an equation with a constant before x

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question is:
How many integer solutions are there to the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + 3x_5 = 80$$
if $x_i$ is greater than or equal to 0?

I understand how to get integer solutions to a regular equation. But the constant before $x_5$ threw me off. Would you divide the answer by $3$? 
My solution was $C(80+5-1, 80)/3$. I think that's wrong

Comment: For each $i = 0, 1, \dots, 26$, count the number of solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 80 - 3i$ using say [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and add them up.

Comment: The solution (of nonnegative $x_i$) is $\sum_{i=0}^{26}{80-3i + 4 - 1 \choose 4-1} = 674541$

Comment: for this solution, you're using the version of stars and bars that require positive integers right? 
the question does say "greater than or equal to 0" so wouldn't you need to use the 2nd version?

Comment: No, as I said *nonnegative $x_i$*, which means "$x_i$ is greater than or equal to 0"! Thanks!

Comment: ah okay, and if the question was _positive $x_i$_ , you would use
(n-1, k-1) formula right?

Comment: Yes, but for the summation $i$ starts at $1$ to $25$ instead. (because $3 \times 26=78$ forces at least two of the other four positive  term to be zero)

Comment: okay makes sense. last question, if the question restricts $i$ to lets say 1-5, the summation will just end at 5 instead of 26 right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(n,k)$ be the way to write $n$ as a sum of $k$ nonnegative integers, the last of which must be divisible by $3$. The number we're looking for is then $A(80,5)$.

As a base case, it is clear that
$$A(n,2)=\lfloor n/3\rfloor+1$$

When $k>2$, imagine writing down all ways to write $n$ as a sum of $k$ numbers with no further restrictions. This can be done in $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$ ways.

For each of the sums where the *last* term is *not* divisible by $3$, subtract $1$ or $2$ from it, and add them instead to the *first* term. In this way each solution arises three times, except the ones with $x_1=0$ (which arise only once) and the ones with $x_1=1$ (which arise twice each).

The number of solutions with $x_1=0$ is $A(n,k-1)$; the number of solutions with $x_1=1$ is $A(n-1,k-1)$. Thus, by keeping track of the overcounting we have
$$ A(n,k) = \frac13\biggl[\binom{n+k-1}{n} + 2A(n,k-1) + A(n-1,k-1)\biggr] $$

With this recurrence, you can compute $A(80,5)$ by dynamic programming just by computing
$$ \begin{matrix} A(77,2) & A(78,2) & A(79,2) & A(80,2) \\ & A(78,3) & A(79,3) & A(80,3) \\ && A(79,4) & A(80,4) \\ &&& A(80,5) \end{matrix} $$
which requires fewer binomial coefficients than it would take to compute the number of solutions separately for the last term being $0,3,6,9,\ldots,78$.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a Visual Basic programm to be run in Excel:

```
Sub Macro1498995()
'
' Macro1498995
'
CONT = 1

For X1 = 0 To 80
For X2 = 0 To 80
For X3 = 0 To 80
For X4 = 0 To 80
For X5 = 0 To 27

Sum = X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + 3 * X5

If Sum = 80 Then
    Cells(CONT, 1) = X1
    Cells(CONT, 2) = X2
    Cells(CONT, 3) = X3
    Cells(CONT, 4) = X4
    Cells(CONT, 5) = X5
    CONT = CONT + 1
End If

Next X5
Next X4
Next X3
Next X2
Next X1
'
End Sub
```

According to this, we have 674541 possibilities.